# Twilio Answering Machine Detection for number dialed with 'Number' node inside 'Dial' node

Tags: twilio

It's not listed anywhere if Answering machine detection will send parameter "**AnsweredBy**" in request when a number is dialed from within a connected call with '**Number**' node. 
I think it doesn't send any such parameter because i'm getting nullpointer exception when i do request.getParameter("AnsweredBy") number dialled by '**number**' node inside '**dial**' node.
Is it that twilio hasn't implemented Answering machine detection fully? or is there any way i can make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio Evangelist here. I'm afraid that currently the [`AnsweredBy` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/answering-machine-detection#new-webhook-parameters) is only available when making an outbound call with the Twilio REST API. If you make the outbound call using TwiML's `<Dial>` then you will not get this parameter.

Depending on your application, if you can use the the REST API instead of TwiML to initiate the call, then you should be able to get this work as you need. But I would need a little more information on what your call flow is to provide any help.

Comment: call flow of application:

1.A call to a _Person1_ is made through Twilio REST API.

2.When _Person1_ picks the call, then call is made to _Person2_ via TwiML.

3.Now I want to check for Answering Machine on _Person2_'s end.

Comment: Additional Details:
when _Person2_ picks up the phone then a greeting is played and _Person1_ can't listen to _Person2_'s side.
In case _Person2_ is an Answering Machine then it has played its message "please leave your message after the beep" by the time _Person1_ can hear _Person2_, so _Person1_ hears silence.
Is there some way I can detect if _Person2_ is Answering Machine or not!?

Comment: You could make both calls with the REST API and then conference them together if Person 2 is not an Answering machine? You should be able to get about the same thing that way..?